# Java ArcGIS program

Tags: arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-sdk-java

Is there any example of how to use the mvc (where interface description is in the fxml file) in ArcGIS using Java?

I want to get suface raster image(my_new_task.tif) on the globe. But my code returns just white screen:

[image]

My fxml interface code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.SceneView?>

<StackPane fx:controller="sample.Controller" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.2" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <SceneView fx:id="sceneView"/>
</StackPane>
```

My Controller code:

```
package sample;

import com.esri.arcgisruntime.layers.Layer;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.layers.RasterLayer;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.ArcGISScene;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.Basemap;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.BasemapStyle;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.Viewpoint;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.SceneView;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.raster.Raster;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private SceneView sceneView;    
    private Basemap basemap;

    public Controller() {
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        this.basemap = new Basemap();
        this.sceneView = new SceneView();
        ArcGISScene scene = new ArcGISScene(this.basemap);
        this.sceneView.setArcGISScene(scene);
        Raster raster = new 
Raster("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\maps\\tif\\my_new_task.tif");
        RasterLayer rasterLayer = new RasterLayer(raster);
        scene.getOperationalLayers().add(rasterLayer);
        rasterLayer.addDoneLoadingListener(() -> {
            if (rasterLayer.getLoadStatus() == LoadStatus.LOADED) {
                System.out.println("raster added");
                Envelope extent = rasterLayer.getFullExtent();
                Viewpoint viewpoint = new Viewpoint(extent);
                this.sceneView.setViewpoint(viewpoint);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }

        });
    }
}
```

My Main code:

```
package sample;

import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.ArcGISScene;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.Basemap;
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.SceneView;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage Stage) throws Exception{

        FXMLLoader loader = new 
FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/sample/sample.fxml"));

        Parent root = loader.load();           
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        Stage.setTitle("MapArcgis");
        Stage.setWidth(800);
        Stage.setHeight(700);

        Stage.setScene(scene);
        Stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"this.sceneView = new SceneView();" in initialize() method was the cause. After deleting it the problem is solved.